# Hide Safari browser built in icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, icons

I want to hide the key icon that suggest save passwords etc .

[I want to hide the key icon that suggest save passwords etc .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF6SG.png)

Comment: This icon is to show the password, not to save it and i think its native icon depending on device you are using.

Comment: Please add your code, and make sure it shows the key icon. Incidentally I can't see the key icon in the image you provide - what am I missing?

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the key icon that suggests using saved (not save) passwords, the one that gives the user a list of usernames? I suspect this is up to the user to do and cannot be overridden but it will be interesting to hear from others whether this is so.